# How can I obtain the original encoded response size when intercepting requests with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using this code to log the encoded response size when loading a page in Chrome:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  page._client.on("Network.loadingFinished", data => {
    console.log("finished", { encodedDataLength: data.encodedDataLength });
  });

  // await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  // page.on("request", async request => {
  //   request.continue();
  // });

  await page.goto("http://example.com");
  await browser.close();
})();
```

This is the output:

> finished { encodedDataLength: 967 }

However, if I uncomment the four lines in the code snippet the output changes to:

> finished { encodedDataLength: 0 }

This does make some sense, since the intercepted request could have been modified in some way by the client, and it would not have been gzipped again afterwards.

However, is there a way to access the original gzipped response size?

---

The Chrome trace also doesn't include the gzipped size:

> "encodedDataLength": 0,
>   "decodedBodyLength": 1270,

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please choose as accepted answer so it doesn't show as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Content-Length` header value for such case.

The good guys at google decided they won't fix [some weird bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=764946) closely related to `encodedDataLength`.

Check the code and result below to see proof.

```
page.on("request", async request => {
  request.continue();
});

// Monitor using _client
page._client.on("Network.responseReceived", ({ response }) => {
  console.log("responseReceived", [
    response.headers["Content-Length"],
    response.encodedDataLength
  ]);
});

page._client.on("Network.loadingFinished", data => {
  console.log("loadingFinished", [data.encodedDataLength]);
});

// Monitor using CDP
const devToolsResponses = new Map();
const devTools = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await devTools.send("Network.enable");

devTools.on("Network.responseReceived", event => {
  devToolsResponses.set(event.requestId, event.response);
});

devTools.on("Network.loadingFinished", event => {
  const response = devToolsResponses.get(event.requestId);
  const encodedBodyLength =
    event.encodedDataLength - response.headersText.length;
  console.log(`${encodedBodyLength} bytes for ${response.url}`);
});
```

Result **without** setRequestInterception:

```
responseReceived [ '606', 361 ]
loadingFinished [ 967 ]
606 bytes for http://example.com/
```

Result **with** setRequestInterception:

```
responseReceived [ '606', 0 ]
loadingFinished [ 0 ]
-361 bytes for http://example.com/
```

Tested with multiple gzip tool. Same result everywhere.
[image]

The `Content-Length` Header is far more reliable in every sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but a lot of response headers don't include the Content-Length.

Comment: Can you share one example url?

Comment: This file for example: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=YT%20Sans%3A300%2C500%2C700

Comment: Are you sure it's gzipped?

Comment: Opps, realized that's not the problem. Silly me.

Comment: Content-Length is not used when the response header Transfer-Encoding is used, usually set to "chunked", or, if the server is HTTP/1.0-compliant, when the "Connection: close" header is given (the body is then supposed to be read until the connection is closed). These are the 3 message framing mechanisms used in HTTP. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3