# Is there a way to get network request information from the browser?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

The developer console in Chrome has a network tab that shows all of the resource requests and timing information. In my application I would like to capture that information and send it to the server for analysis if an issue is detected without the need for user intervention. Ideally I'd even like to export it as a HAR file.

A browser extension won't work for my use case. I'm also aware of the [PerformanceAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API), but that only provides timing information. It does not include any request or response information.

So is there a way to capture all of the information from the network tab programmatically?

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969381/how-can-i-capture-all-network-requests-and-full-response-data-when-loading-a-pag for chrome

Comment: That question is asking how to do it using Puppeteer. That does not fit my use case since I need this to work from the running application code.