# How to save Json response on puppeteer JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, response

We can launch browser in controlled environment on Node.js for example:

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: true
   });
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('https://www.oddsportal.com/');
   await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 941 });
      await page.waitForSelector('.flex:nth-child(2) > .bg-gray-extra_dark > .h-\     [16px\]');
   await page.click('.flex:nth-child(2) > .bg-gray-extra_dark > .h-\[16px\]');
   await browser.close();
 })();
```

Usually browser generated a lot of Json-files, for example

[image: Json response]

How to save this response? Directly with Puppeteer or with Chrome Developer Tools.
If I understand this is two different methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969381/how-can-i-capture-all-network-requests-and-full-response-data-when-loading-a-pag
something like this?

Comment: @cmgchess, yes, thanks, this is cool solution I searching, one of the way. Second way is using functions of Chrome DevTools only, isn't it? I want to try both of it, because real site I need to parse is strong and sophisticated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Chrome DevTools only" and why would it be any different than using `page.on("response")`?

Comment: @ggorlen, for me there are serial of command what allow manipulate with site directly from command line, for example this is most spread socket inspector command - devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000 ,  this is not related to Puppiteer, I was faced with webscrapper based on ChromeTools Only. And second Chrome/FF opportunity. also not related with Puppeteer, is tracing options (chrome://tracing/ ), its possible there are direct command allow to manipulate Chrome Tracer directly from command line (like command to call socket inspector). Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for explaining--I'm not familiar with these APIs, just Puppeteer, so I'll follow along and see what winds up being the answer here.

Comment: @ggorlen, Puppeteer is cool solution, thank you for your answer, but this is not all possible solution. There are a couple another opportunity embedded to browser.