# What wrong in Puppeteer technology, why most site show another view on directly browsing and browsing with Puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I do checked a serious of sites directly and with Puppeteer with that code [How can I capture all network requests and full response data when loading a page in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969381/how-can-i-capture-all-network-requests-and-full-response-data-when-loading-a-pag)
Starting from https://www.oddsportal.com/ to https://www.freelancer.com/
Result always was different from direct browsing, for example

[image]

In all checking I have add cookies (I have copy they from browser), but all sites I checked show different view than expected.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] as [text, not a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). We'd have to retype or use OCR to be able to run this code, assuming all of it were visible in the screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website owners usually don't like it when someone reads their data automatically. Often it is also forbidden in the terms of use. Anyway, Puppeteer is known to do something like that. So, the web servers (or other parties) try to figure out if a real user is visiting their site or not.

If you use Puppeteer in the default configuration, it reveals itself directly via the user-agent header (you can see this e.g. via [responsler](https://www.responsler.com): just choose a hostname there and request it via Puppeteer to see the request in detail).

Furthermore, there are many other, more complicated ways to identify Puppeteer from a real user (mainly javascript-based). To bypass this complicated bot detection, there is for example the [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth), which is specialized in this.

**But always pay attention to the legal regulations and do not do anything forbidden!**